# Fully qualify window path after upgrading to QTP 11?

Tags: automated-testing, qtp

After I upgraded from QTP 10 to 11, it required me to fully qualify my window paths using descriptive programming.

For example, this sort of thing used to work in QTP 10:

```
Window("Main").Window("PopupDialog).Click("OK")
```

Now, I am required to specify the entire path to get to the dialog:

```
Window("Main").Window("IntermediateWindow").Window("PopupDialog").Click("OK")
```

Is there an option or some way that I can tell QTP to dynamically figure out the path as it used to in the previous version?

Comment: Unless your application has changed this sounds like a defect in QTP 11, have you contacted support?

Comment: I have not yet, no. I thought perhaps this would yield a better, faster, and stronger answer.

Comment: Perhaps it still will but there *are* some problems the internet can't solve...

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on stackoverflow, I see this site has 4 QTP questions which SO has over 200 so there's more of a chance you'll get an answer.

Comment: True, but then that won't help to generate content here...

Comment: That's not descriptive programming as all the objects are identified by objects names instead of description string. Is it possible that someone changed the object repository?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on both the versions of QTP but the issue isn't came to me, it can be happening due to below issues:

1. Check the browser which you are working on is not upgraded, like IE8 to IE9
2. Check for the OR if you have created one.
3. Try writing descriptive script properly as `Window("name:=main").Page`
4. I guess its scripting issue not QTP.

Try for the IE you are working like IE 9, you have all patches installed.